# Airflow is exposing secret values through logging

Tags: python, airflow-2.x, secret-key

I have an Airflow 2.2.5 cluster. Some of the dags are exposing secrets when looking at their console log.

[Airflow docs for this version](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.2.5/security/secrets/mask-sensitive-values.html) say that Airflow should by default mask values from JSON keys with the following names: `('access_token', 'api_key', 'apikey','authorization', 'passphrase', 'passwd', 'password', 'private_key', 'secret', 'token')`

However, this is not happening in my cluster, where I got a json blob, let's say `extra_foo`, with 2 keys in particular: `private_key` and `private_key_id`. Their values are being printed in plaintext.

The next thing the docs mention is to use `mask_secret`, however, the docs on it seem to be really poor, as it only says to call `mask_secret("custom_value")`, but when looking at the actual implementation of the method, it's the following:

```
def mask_secret(secret: Union[str, dict, Iterable], name: str = None) -> None:
    """
    Mask a secret from appearing in the task logs.

    If ``name`` is provided, then it will only be masked if the name matches
    one of the configured "sensitive" names.

    If ``secret`` is a dict or a iterable (excluding str) then it will be
    recursively walked and keys with sensitive names will be hidden.
    """
    # Delay import
    from airflow import settings

    # Filtering all log messages is not a free process, so we only do it when
    # running tasks
    if not settings.MASK_SECRETS_IN_LOGS or not secret:
        return

    _secrets_masker().add_mask(secret, name)
```

So the method does not just take a str, it mainly takes a `Union[str, dict, Iterable]` and docs on this class are also very limited (actually non existent as far as I've looked).
I still tried to call `mask_secret("private_key_id")` and `mask_secret("private_key")`, however, two interesting things are happening: Airflow is ONLY masking the name of the key, and it's also only masking the substring `"private_key"` (so in practice it looks like `***_id: actual secret in plaintext`)

So it seems like it only applies the last mask, and even then, it's not masking the value related to the key.

Is there a better way to mask these secret values?